# trying to query a database based on date range would doesn't this work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mern

```
something.aggregate().match({
     createdAt: { $gte: '2020-03-02', $lte: '2021-03-02' },
   });
```

(also tried wrapping the dates in ISODate an Date)
returns an empty list

example db entry

```
{
    "_id": ,
    "createdAt": "2020-09-10T18:56:15.094Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-09-10T18:56:15.094Z",
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

needed to do

```
new Date('2020-03-02')
```